# Is it bad practice to initialize variables before calling onCreate?

Tags: android, initialization, instance-variables

I have been wondering, as I'm new to Android, if it's bad practice to initialize a variable such as a Context object, in the fields declaration of a class before calling onCreate(). I am pasting a picture of what I'm talking about. Take a look at how and when I initialize the Context object. When is this instantiated compared to onCreate and can I trust it to be initialized everytime I call this class?

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can't use a `context` before `onCreate` is called.  It won't be fully initialized.  You can save it in a variable whenever though.

The real question is-  why the heck are you doing this at all?  There is no reason to save a copy of this in a class variable unless its static, since you can always reference it as this.  And you should never save a static `Context`.

Comment: What about other variables? Is it unwise to initialize an array before on create. I’m not saying these are tactics I’m using but by accident I realized it worked. I just want to fully understand it. So other than the context, is it just as unwise to initialize variables like lists and others?

Comment: No, there's no problem instantiating lists or the like that way.  The only problem is if the right hand side of the equal includes a call to a variable that is not yet fully initialized (requires a call other than its constructor to be fully usable).  That's fairly rare, but Contexts are notable exceptions. 
 Whether you should or not is more a personal style choice.

Comment: As the pciture shows you "can",as it compiles, so the answer is wrong. You "shouldn't" because it might be null, is a different topic

Comment: @CaptainCrunch No, you can't.  It will compile, but the variable will not be initialized and will not work properly.  So you can't *actually* do it.  The fact that it compiles doesn't mean it works.  And in this case you're wrong it can't be null, as the this keyword is never null.

Answer (score -1):

initialize Context inside onCreate() that will not fail. It will initialize everytime when you call this class.